# How to initialize a old version Spring Boot project (for example, 2.3.x.RELEASE)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Now, there is no version option `2.3.x.RELEASE` in https://start.spring.io/ .

Is there any tool (prefer official) that works like https://start.spring.io/ and I can choose to use the old version of Spring Boot and related dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the version value in pom.xml in your IDE.

*Example :*

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<!--Change the value here as per your need-->   <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure whether this way cause some error so I want to get a way that is more "official".

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function send() {
            var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
             const data = {
                  "departmentName": name,
                  "departmentId": id,
                  "departmentAddress": address,
                  "departmentCode": code,
            };
            console.log(data);

 $.post({
  dataType : "json",
url:"api/postStudents",
data:JSON.stringify(data),
contentType : 'application/json',
});
}
function update() {
            var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
             const data = {
                  "departmentName": name,
                  "departmentId": id,
                  "departmentAddress": address,
                  "departmentCode": code,
            };
            console.log(data);

$.ajax({
  dataType : "json",
   type: 'PUT',
url:"api/updateStudents",
data:JSON.stringify(data),
contentType : 'application/json',
});
}


    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div class="center-screen">

        <h1>I</h1>

        <h3>REGISTRATION</h3>
        <br>
        <text>Enter Student Name     : </text>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></br>
        <br>
          <text>Enter Student Id     : </text>
        <input type="number" id="id" placeholder="id" /></br>
        <br>
         <text>Enter Student Address : </text>
        <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="address" \n/></br>
        <br>
         <text>Enter Student Code:</text>
        <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="code"/></br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="send()">Register</button>
        <button onclick="update()">Update</button></br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).